# Can I decorate Joiner class of Guava

Tags: java, guava

I have a `List<String>` and we are using Joiner to get the comma separated presentation of that List but now we need to do little enhancement, We need to capitalize the values in the List. Now the code was -

```
String str = Joiner.on(',').skipNulls().join(myValueList);
```

But now as I need to capitalize the Strings present in values I need to iterate it first to capitalize and then pass to Joiner to join, but I den't think this is a good approach as it'll iterate the List twice, one to capitalize and then Joiner will iterate to Join.
 
Is there any other utility method that I'm missing which may do this in one iteration. 
How will you do it with Guava?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [`Iterables.transform()`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#transform(java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Function))

```
Iterable<String> upperStrings = Iterables.transform(myValueList, new Function<String,String>() {
  public String apply(String input) {
    // any transformation possible here.
    return (input == null) ? null : input.toUpperCase();
  }
});
Str str = Joiner.on(',').skipNulls().join(upperStrings);
```

Comment: I don't question your answer. Just a comment - how is it better than a simple for-loop iterating over the list of strings? The readability of the Guava approach is poor.

Comment: @Grzegorz: one advantage is that you don't create a copy of `myValueList`. The `Iterable` returned lazily calls the method specified and can thus potentially safe quite some memory. I agree that the code doesn't look nice. Unfortunately closures won't arrive soon in Java.

Comment: The main reason I wrote it like that is because the question explicitly asks for a Guava solution, 'though ;-)

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd +1, @Joachim +1, Yes, but I liked both and given the fact that transformation will happen lazily at the time of join call, performance will be the same.. right?

Comment: @Premraj almost right. In my case, the enum will only be created once, while the anonymous function will be created once per call. But we're talking nanoseconds here.

Comment: @Grzegorz  a function like this is also parallizable, not that guava implements this yet, but is has been don in the Scala collactions (.view.par.map) http://vimeo.com/25830116

Answer (score 15):

About Joachim Sauer's answer:

it can be made a lot less verbose if you move the Function to a place where it can be re-used, in Guava the typical scenario would be to use an enum:

```
public enum StringTransformations implements Function<String, String>{
    LOWERCASE{

        @Override
        protected String process(final String input){
            return input.toLowerCase();
        }
    },
    UPPERCASE{
        @Override
        protected String process(final String input){
            return input.toUpperCase();
        }
    }
    // possibly more transformations here
    ;

    @Override
    public String apply(final String input){
        return input == null ? null : process(input);
    }

    protected abstract String process(String input);

}
```

Now the client code looks like this:

```
String str =
    Joiner
        .on(',')
        .skipNulls()
        .join(
            Iterables.transform(myValueList,
                StringTransformations.UPPERCASE));
```

Which I'd call much more readable.

Of course it would be even better (in terms of both memory usage and performance) if you introduced a constant for your Joiner:

```
private static final Joiner COMMA_JOINER = Joiner.on(',').skipNulls();

// ...

String str = COMMA_JOINER.join(
            Iterables.transform(myValueList,
                StringTransformations.UPPERCASE));
```

Comment: I like the idea of using `enums`! I've been using static methods returning the `Function` objects instead, but this is much cleaner.

Comment: You sometimes need the static methods anyway when you need to return a Function within certain generic bounds. Many of Guava's static factory methods use enums internally, but need the factory method just for it's translation of generics.

Comment: I think it's a best practice to *always* expose functions as static factories, for flexibility (generics or not). The implementation will often use the enum singleton pattern, but it is an implementation detail and could change. Plus, when using an enum, all your functions must have the same generic types (you can't have both Function<Integer,String> and Function<String,String> on the same enum). Guava does this too: http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/common/base/Functions.java?r=138#48 (see toStringFunction() / identity()).

Answer (score -1):

How about the following?

```
Joiner.on(',').skipNulls().join(myValueList).toUpperCase()
```

Comment: True, but I think he meant capitalize as in: uppercase the first letter of each word (I've got that wrong too :-))